# Set up react native app to listen to external keyboard inputs

Tags: ios, react-native, keyboard, accessibility

I'm trying to add accessibility features to a react-native app. One of the asks is to allow users to be able to navigate and interact with the app using a keyboard and/or other assistive input devices. I was looking through the docs and came across the Android support for external keyboards [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/navigation) that could help with the tab button navigation like in html. And I think it corresponds to the react native properties [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#nextfocusdown-android). But these only seem available to Android. Is there similar support for iOS that I can access in my react native apps.